# Upgrade Jersey to 2.15 ResourceConfig adding any definition to the object loses all the configuration

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I have upgraded My Jersey application to from 1.x to 2.15.  Im working on converting all the Injection bindings and other customizations from the previous version.  The base setup is working if I leave the "JerseyApplication extends ResourseConfig" constructor without any definition.  When I add an AbstractBinding everything stops working.  Heres the setup:

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!--<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>-->
        <version>2.15</version>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.services.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JerseyApplication.java

```
package com.services;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication(){

    }
}
```

SimpleService.java

```
package com.services.shop;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Path("/simple")
@Service
public class SimpleService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Foo> get() {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        foo1.setName("Tester 1");
        foo1.setBar("Apple");
        foo1.setNumber(1234);

        Foo foo2 = new Foo();
        foo2.setName("Tester 2");
        foo2.setBar("Green");
        foo2.setNumber(5678);

        List<Foo> results = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        results.add(foo1);

        return results;
    }
}
```

Foo.java

```
package com.services.shop;

/**
 * Created by pmefford on 2/12/15.
 */
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private String bar;
    private Integer number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 49
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:31:39 GMT

[{"name":"Tester 1","bar":"Apple","number":1234}]
```

Once I start to configure ResourceConfig it fails:
Changed JerseyApplication.java

```
package com.services;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication(){
        packages("com.services");
    }
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:34:10 GMT
Connection: close

<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Spring Web Application threw exception</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Spring Web Application threw exception</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Spring Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/server/impl/inject/AbstractHttpContextInjectable
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:402)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:397)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:262)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:224)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:697)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:892)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:849)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:1123)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:1181)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1150)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:322)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.AbstractHttpContextInjectable
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:402)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$7.run(ReflectionHelper.java:397)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:262)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:224)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:697)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:892)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:849)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:1123)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:1181)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1150)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:322)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
```

I need to be able to configure this because I would like to register an AbstractBinders as follows:

```
register(new AbstractBinder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindFactory(LocaleInjectionFactory.class).to(Locale.class);
    }
})
```

So my question is why can't I register packages or other object without losing the "default" configuration.  I would like to append my config to whats there instead of explicitly define everything.

Comment: The fact that it's looking for a class in a com.sun.jersey.* package is kinda scary. Are you sure that you removed all of the Jersey 1 dependencies?

Comment: good point.  I didn't notice that.  I'll look into why that is.  My main struggle is with understanding how jersey works with Application.  And in jersey 1.x I followed this example http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-injection-providers/ which may have not been a good idea to add Locale to the context via (@Context Locale locale)